# Wix Burn select msi and apply mst dynamically

Tags: wpf, wix, windows-installer, burn

I have MSI's in english, german and a MST transform file for german installer.

Now in burn boostrapper how to bundle these MSI's and MST's so that appropriate localized MST is applied to the msi during runtime ?

```
<Bundle ....>
 <Chain>
  <PackageGroupRef Id='Netfx4Full' />
  <PackageGroupRef Id='SQLServerCompact4.0' />   
  <MsiPackage Id="EN_MSI_x86"
              SourceFile="$(var.MsiDir_x86)MyApp_x86.msi"
              Compressed="yes" EnableFeatureSelection="no" Vital="yes" Visible="no"
              InstallCondition="NOT VersionNT64">             
    <MsiProperty Name="INSTALL_LANG" Value="1033" />      
    <MsiProperty Name="TRANSFORMS" Value="[SystemLanguageID].mst"/>
    <Payload Id="1031.mst" Compressed="yes" Name="de-localization" SourceFile="$(var.MsiDir_x86)1031.mst" />
  </MsiPackage>
</Chain>
</Bundle>
```

Is this the right way to include MST in the bundle ?

Comment: Did you get this to work?  I'm trying to do the same thing.

Comment: No. I generated only one versions of MSI which has localized assembly for all languages we support. After installation the user can change language of his choice from the program itself.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the error is in the payload attributes. If you swap the values of `Id` an `Name` it should work. The msi installer looks for a file named `1031.mst` but you named it `de-localization`.